# What is the convention for documenting arguments passed to a callback in javascript?

Tags: javascript, documentation, javadoc

When using a javadoc-style documenting style, is there a convention for documenting the arguments passed to a callback function?

```
/**
 * @param cb {Function} A callback that will be passed a name (String) and a Number
/
```

Comment: [Annotating JS for the Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types) suggests using `{function(String, Number)}` for that. No guarantees that that is supported by your IDE.

Comment: Thanks!

I care more about the convention, less about compatibility with my specific IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This is more related to events than callbacks, but I wanted to post it as it may help you in related cases. If you also fire an event when the callback is called, you could use this approach to document the event, then, in your callback documentation, note that it receives the same parameters as the event and link to the event using @link.

I use something like what you see below to document events in [F.js](http://lazd.github.com/F/). It's not connected to any specific code, and I have it dumped at the bottom of the script that defines F.Component:

```
/**
 * Triggered when this component is shown
 *
 * @name F.Component#component:shown
 * @event
 *
 * @param {Object}  evt                 Event object
 * @param {String}  evt.name            This component's name
 * @param {F.Component} evt.component   This component
 */
```

The above JSDoc statement results in [documentation that looks like this](http://lazd.github.com/F/F/jsdoc/symbols/F.Component.html) when built using jsdoc-toolkit. Basically, you get a nice Event Detail section that describes when the event is triggered and what parameters are passed to the callback. This also works with JSDoc3, and results in an Events section with the same information.

Do note that the [documentation describing the @event tag](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagEvent) doesn't exactly describe it to be used in this fashion, but it does give the desired output. As far JSDoc3, the [@event](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-event.html) and [@fires](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-fires.html) tags do not have documentation yet, but @event does give the output I was looking for.

Comment: I like it! But I'm not sure it's the convention (if there is one)